# Detecting unresolved functions in eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to get eslint to warn if it thinks there is an unresolved function in Javascript. I'm experimenting with the 'default' config from eslint and a basic Javascript class like this:

```
class Test {
    doStuff() {
        console.log('Doing stuff');
    }
}

const test = new Test();
// ok 
test.doStuff();
// doh! 
test.nothingHere();
```

Is there some way to get eslint to warn that "nothingHere" may be unresolved and will potentially crash with a TypeError?

Comment: This is more the purview of a type checker like Flow or TypeScript or Google Closure